# Angular --prod build failing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My team is currently working on our first Angular/Angular-cli application.  While our project builds and works find using JIT compiling we're experiencing performance issues with IE 11 so I wanted to get a feel for IE performance when AOT is used (building with the with the --prod parameter).  Unfortunately the build fails and, being inexperienced, I don't fully understand the error or what to do about it.

The error:

```
[ERROR] ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class BaseSopPanelComponent in /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/app/components/base-sop-panel/base-sop-panel.component.ts! Add BaseSopPanelComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
[ERROR] ERROR in ./src/main.ts
[ERROR] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src'
[ERROR] resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src'
[ERROR]   using description file: /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/package.json (relative path: ./src)
[ERROR]     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]   after using description file: /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/package.json (relative path: ./src)
[ERROR]     using description file: /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory)
[ERROR]       no extension
[ERROR]         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
[ERROR]       .ts
[ERROR]         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
[ERROR]       .js
[ERROR]         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
[ERROR]       as directory
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory]
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts]
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.js]
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory]
```

BaseSopPanelComponent is a base class for 6 or 7 of our components. The constructor signature is:

```
  constructor(public readonly dataService: SopDataService, public readonly name: string)
```

After adding BaseSopPanelComponent to app.modules I get the error

```
[ERROR] ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for BaseSopPanelComponent in /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/app/components/base-sop-panel/base-sop-panel.component.ts: ([object Object], ?).
[ERROR] ERROR in ./src/main.ts
[ERROR] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src'
[ERROR] resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src'
[ERROR]   using description file: /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/package.json (relative path: ./src)
[ERROR]     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]   after using description file: /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/package.json (relative path: ./src)
[ERROR]     using description file: /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/package.json (relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory)
[ERROR]       no extension
[ERROR]         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
[ERROR]       .ts
[ERROR]         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
[ERROR]       .js
[ERROR]         Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
[ERROR]       as directory
[ERROR]         /Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory]
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts]
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.js]
[ERROR] [/Users/brife/svn/lms/sop/branches/current/ng2/src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory]
[ERROR]  @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
[ERROR]  @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is it supposed to be getting its name from? You need an injection token, or a factory provider. Read the DI docs.

Comment: do you have BaseSopPanelComponent in you declarations of module ?

Comment: BaseSopPanelComponent is a base class, the parameters are injected when the subclass is instantiated.  Angular should not need to inject parameters

Comment: Originally I didn't, but when added to the module list, Angular complains about the constructor parameter injection.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  The component base class was incorrectly annotated with @Component.  There was no UI associated with the component and after determining that @Components can extend non components I removed the annotation which allowed a --prod build to finish successfully